# How to make tabular legend using matplotlib and python

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, legend

I am plotting a choropleth map in python from a shapefile and i want to customize the legend of the plot, i am using the code bellow:

```
import pandas as pd
import pysal as ps
import geopandas as gp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pth = 'outcom.shp'
tracts = gp.GeoDataFrame.from_file(pth)
ax = plot_dataframe(tracts, column='Density', scheme='QUANTILES', k=4, colormap=plt.cm.Blues, legend=True)
plt.show()
```

Besides, i am using a small patch that i found here  http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/jorisvandenbossche/d4e6efedfa1e4e91ab65 in order to visualize the legend.

here's my result :
[image]
But, i need something similar to this :

[image]

so my question now, is how can i have a customized legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [`plt.table`](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.table.html) as a legend.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

valeur = np.array([.1,.45,.7])
text=[["Faible","Ng<1,5" ],["Moyenne","1,5<Ng<2,5"],[u"Elevée", "Ng>2,5"]]
colLabels = ["Exposition", u"Densité"]


tab=plt.table(cellText=text, colLabels=colLabels, 
                    colWidths = [0.2,0.2], loc='lower right', 
                    cellColours=plt.cm.hot_r(np.c_[valeur,valeur]))

plt.show()
```

In order to link this table to a contourf plot, you may do as follows:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.sort(np.random.rand(100)).reshape(10,10)*4

levels = np.array([0,1.5,2.5,4])
sm = plt.contourf(a, levels = levels, cmap=plt.cm.hot_r )


text=[["Faible","Ng<1,5" ],["Moyenne","1,5<Ng<2,5"],[u"Elevée", "Ng>2,5"]]
colLabels = ["Exposition", u"Densité"]

col = levels[:-1] + np.diff(levels)/2.
cellcol = sm.cmap(sm.norm(np.c_[col,col]))

tax = plt.gcf().add_axes([0,0,1,1])
tab=tax.table(cellText=text, colLabels=colLabels, 
                    colWidths = [0.2,0.2], loc='lower left', 
                    cellColours=cellcol )

tax.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I did as you said , but it's like there is no link between the map and the table, i got a result showing a map with the default colors and in the bottom there is the table you coded1.

Comment: I updated the answer to make the legend use colors from a contourplot.

Comment: well I really appreciate your help, but i'm not using contourf plot , it's a choropleth map and i'm using this : ax = plot_dataframe(tracts, column='Density', scheme='QUANTILES', k=4, colormap=plt.cm.Blues, legend=True) , and the dataframe does not support the 'levels'.

Comment: I understand that, but this geopandas function you're using is a little complicated and you already asked a new question about that, so I decided to give the general solution as answer to this question.

Comment: For how to use this legend in an actual geopandas plot, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44607398/4124317).